# Remove ' ' before and after ()

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, codeigniter

From the code below i get a sql query :

```
SELECT * FROM `tblstaff` WHERE `active` = 1 AND role IN '(10,7,4,5)'
AND staffid IN '(3,8,9,12,2 )' AND `is_not_staff` =0 ORDER BY
`firstname` DESC
```

with the '()' n which makes the query wrong the values comes from $staffids and $roleid and this ia a string so when converted to associated array it gives the output in **'(10,2,5)'**. So how to remove the **''** from the query.

```
      if ($staff_role != STAFF_ROLE_SALE_AGENT_FTD_ID && $staff_role != STAFF_ROLE_SALE_AGENT_RETENTION_ID && ($view_own || $view )){
            if(get_staff_role() == STAFF_ROLE_ADMIN_ID){  
                $where['role NOT IN '] = "( ". STAFF_ROLE_SA_ID ." )" ; 
            } else{
                    $roleids = get_immediate_roleids();
                    if($roleids != ''){
                        $where['role IN'] = '('. $roleids .')';                
                    }
                }
            if($staff_role != STAFF_ROLE_SA_ID){
                if($view_own){
                    $staffids = get_immediate_staffids($staff_id); echo $staffids;
                    $where['staffid IN'] =  $staffids ." )" ;
                } else if(is_numeric($staff_office_id) && $staff_office_id > 0){
                        $staffids = get_immediate_staffids_under_office('', $staff_office_id);echo $staffids;
                        $where['staffid IN'] = "(". $staffids  ." )" ;
                    }
            }
```

Comment: are you using active CI query builder? can you show me query builder code?

Comment: $where['is_not_staff'] = 0;               
                $data['members'] = $this->staff_model->get('', 1,$where);

Comment: $data['members'] = $this->staff_model->get('', 1,$where);       In  $data['members'] it is storing

Comment: in model if you are using $this->db->where then use it like this $this->db->where($where,null,FALSE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CI query builder you have to change the approach :

Replace this : 
         $where['role NOT IN '] = "( ". STAFF_ROLE_SA_ID ." )" ; 
With :
         $this->db->where_not_in('role',STAFF_ROLE_SA_ID);
and same as for Where In Clause :
            $this->db->where_in('staffid',$staffids);